# How to filter multiple files and eliminate duplicate entries to select a single entry while using linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a folder that contains several files. These files consist of identical columns.
Let us say file1 and file2 have contents as follows.(Here it can be more than two files)

```
 
$cat file1.txt 
9999999999|1200
8888888888|1400
7777777777|1255
6666666666|1788
7777777777|1289
9999999999|1300


$cat file2.txt 
9999999999|2500
8888888888|2450
6666666666|2788
9999999999|3000
2222222222|3001
```

In my file 1st column is mobile number and 2nd is count. Same mobile can be there in multiple files. Now I want to get the records into a file with unique mobile numbers which has the highest count.
The output should be as follows:

```
$cat output.txt
7777777777|1289
8888888888|2450
6666666666|2788
9999999999|3000
2222222222|3001
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put here what you've done so far

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not very efficient but it does the job:
put this into phones.sh and run `sh phones.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
files="
file1.txt 
file2.txt
"
phones=$(cat $files | cut -d'|' -f1 | sort -u)
for phone in $phones; do grep -h $phone $files | sort -t'|' -k 2 -nr | head -n1; done | sort -t'|' -k 2
```

What it does is basically, extract all the phone numbers in the files, iterate over them and grep them in all files, select the one with the highest count. Then I also sorted the final result by count, which is what your expected result suggests. `sort -t'|' -k 2 -nr` means sort the second column given the delimiter `|`, by decreasing numerical order. `head -n1` selects the first line. You can add other files into the `files` variable.

Comment: i want to use ls -ltrh in place of file names and i want to sort files one by one not all files at a time....
first i want to sort first 2 files and put into new file and then i want to sort 3rd file and new file and put into same new file then sort 4th ,new file and put it into new file...and so on,at last i want a new files which is sorted.please help me

Comment: It is hard to understand what you really want, but I think you may start to learn the basics of shell scripting. I guess my answer does not need much modification to achieve what you need. By the way [parsing ls is not recommended](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls). You should use `find` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is to use the power of `sort` and `awk`:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort -t '|' -k1,1 -k2,2nr | awk -F"|" '!_[$1]++' | sort -t '|' -k2,2n
```

I think the one-liner is pretty self-explanatory, except for the `awk`. What that part does is that it does a `uniq` by the first column. The last sort is just to get the final order that you wanted.